# What are the top visualization tools out there for threat investigation?

Tags: tools, research

cybersecurity professionals! I'm a researcher at a large danish university, and I've been fortunate to secure funding for a project aimed at enhancing the visualization of threat investigations in cybersecurity - e.g. visualization tools that can utilized with the purpose of closing or escalating incidents. The thing is, I'm a data analyst and a UX researcher - not a cybersecurity professional.

While the project grant is tied to a larger american cybersecurity consultancy as SMEs, I'd love to hear some other perspectives than theirs. So I'm reaching out to your community, to get some input.

1. Are you currently utilizing visualization tools in your incident investigations, what dissuades/motivates your use of them?
2. Which tools specifically are you seeing being utilized?
3. What features or capabilities do you believe would significantly improve the effectiveness of incident investigation visualizations?

This, or any other input on this topic will help shape our research. Thank you for your insights!

*Bonus: As an insight in some of the work we're doing, I'm happy to share these three findings that surprised me (a non-cybersecurity-professional) from observing defenders investigating threats - maybe they can spark some discussion as well:*

- *Defenders constantly pivots between a multitude of tabs and tools
  (~17 tools were observed on average for a single investigation).*
- *Documentation/communication consumes about 50% of total time spent.*
- *Decision-making is largely based on experience, often ignoring
  software recommendations*

Edit: Formatting